# iOS/XCode 6: Tips for when to connect storyboard with code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I'm a beginner programmer and could do with as many 'pointers' as possible (or not!) :/

Just wondering if anyone can give me some guidelines on when controls, etc., added via the interface builder to your storyboard in Xcode 6, need to be connected to in your code?

I guess I'm looking for some general, and more specific, guidelines on what exactly you do in interface builder needs to be qualified in your code?

If there is something you do in the interface builder that you need to tell your code?

I know there is a lot but I am just looking for a kind of summary overview I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get or change the property of some object you made in IB, then you should make an IBOutlet to it.

If you have a control (button, switch, slider, etc.) that sends an action method, you should connect it to an IBAction in your code. You don't need to do this if you connect a segue up from a control since the segue is executed by touching the control (a button or cell generally).

You don't need to connect a view with the code, if you're not accessing it. For instance, some views might just be containers to hold other views, so you might not need to do anything with them.

There are exceptions to these generalizations of course. You could make an IBOutlet to a button, and add its action and target in code, but that's not generally how you would do it (except for buttons in table view or collection view cells, where this technique is quite common). You can also access views by their tag (with viewWithTag:), so it's not an absolute necessity to have an IBOutlet to access a view, though generally it would be better to have one.